# I import fizzy steam works and get errors

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-mirror

When I import fizzy steam works I get these 2 errors

Assets\Mirror\Runtime\Transport\FizzySteamworks\LegacyServer.cs(27,71): error CS7036: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'arg3' of 'Action<int, TransportError, string>.Invoke(int, TransportError, string)'

and

Assets\Mirror\Runtime\Transport\FizzySteamworks\NextServer.cs(42,71): error CS7036: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'arg3' of 'Action<int, TransportError, string>.Invoke(int, TransportError, string)'

please help

I tried importing steam works foundation because I saw that it fixed it somewhere on a forrum

Comment: I doing this with fizzy works 4.4.1

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the last steamworks.NET? The latest version of FizzySteamworks is 5.1 and you are using 4.4.1, maybe update it and you'll be free of those errors

Answer (score 0):

I faced with the same error and I just changed Invoke method name to DynamicInvoke method. For now it seems like working fine in my project.